# YouTube age-restriction bug

Tags: google-account, stock-android, youtube, google-apps, bugs

I am asking this question on this site as I have a problem with the YouTube app: So, I happen to be a teenager under 18 and have a Gmail id that I use with YouTube. Now everything was fine until something came upon me and I decided to upload videos on YouTube. So, I made a separate YouTube account but with the **same Gmail id**. So now I was browsing videos with my regular ID and saw that one video was age restricted and I could not view it. So, I switched my ID to my uploading channel(that actually used the same Gmail id) in the YouTube app and bam!I could see that video with just a warning about the content being inappropriate for some users.( I haven't tried it on the YouTube website yet)
So,  I have these questions:

1. Is this actually a bug in YouTube or is it supposed to be this way?
2. If it is a bug, has it already been reported but not fixed yet because google employees don't view this as an issue?
3. Should I report it(I  don't know how to)? As I think parents might be concerned about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this actually a bug in YouTube or is it supposed to be this way?

Being that when you open a new channel, it doesn't ask you for your date of birth, that means that it's using your main accounts date of birth. In that case according to the system you are under 18 and so I'll have to conclude that this is a bug.

> If it is a bug, has it already been reported but not fixed yet because
>   google employees don't view this as an issue?

Being that bugs are reported privately to Google, there is no way for us to know whether this one was ever reported.

> Should I report it(I don't know how to)? As I think parents might be
>   concerned about this.

You should definitely report it. I look at this as possibly a security bug, therefore, I suggest you report it [here.](https://www.google.com/appserve/security-bugs/m2/new?rl=&key=) this page is specifically for reporting bugs, and you might even be eligible for a reward!

Comment: Thanks for such a great answer, but I can't seem to figure out which category this bug belongs to.

Comment: @AnuragThakur maybe the last one "I want to report a scam, malware, **or other problems not listed above**"

Comment: Done, but I don't think there would be any further correspondence ( the page just tells me to visit a website to learn tips)